# How do I use the InnerHTML to output the data?

Tags: javascript, html

Having a hard time figuring out why my program won't post the results.  Any assistance would be appreciated.  Still really new to programming and HTML/javascript.  I can't figure out why the result won't actually work.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<title>Rummage it All</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-
 JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" 
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/homework.css" type="text/css" 
media="screen">
</head>
<!--Navigation to different links and parts of the website-->
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">CS240</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Products</a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Rummage Items</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Unique Items</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Love that Ink Pen Company</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="dropdown02" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Who we are</a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown02">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">About Us</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Our Vision</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Contact Us</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="dropdown03" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Links</a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown03">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="../pages/home.html">Home</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="../pages/week1-1.html">Week 1-1</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="../pages/week1-2.html">Week 1-2</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="../pages/week2-1.html">Week 2-1</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="../pages/week2-2.html">Week 2-2</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="../pages/week3-1.html">Week 3-1</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="../pages/week3-2.html">Week 3-2</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="../pages/week4-1.html">Week 4-1</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="../pages/week4-2.html">Week 4-2</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="../pages/week5-1.html">Week 5-1</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="../pages/week5-2.html">Week 5-2</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="../pages/week6-1.html">Week 6-1</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="../pages/week6-2.html">Week 6-2</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="../pages/week7-1.html">Week 7-1</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="../pages/week7-2.html">Week 7-2</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="../pages/week8-1.html">Week 8-1</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="../pages/week8-2.html">Week 8-2</a>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit"></button>
        </form>
    </div>
</nav>

<main role="main">

    <!--Main jumbotron-->
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <h1 class="display-3">Registration</h1>
            <p>Please fill out the information</p>
            <blockquote class="blockquote text-center">
                <p class="mb-0">"Rummage through it all!"</p>
                <footer class="blockquote-footer">Someone Awesome <cite title="Source Title"></cite></footer>
            </blockquote>
        </div>
        <!--Card to display a logo-->
        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem; color:black">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="../images/registration.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title"></h5>
                <p class="card-text">Register Today!</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <form style="background:url(../images/Backgroundcontainer.png)">
        <div class="container-fluid">

            <h1>Registration Form</h1>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <label for="pass">Password:</label>
                    <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" size="30" placeholder="Minimum 10 characters long" />
                </li>

                <li>
                    <label for="name">Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="user_name" id="name" size="50" placeholder="Firstname, LastName Mi" />
                </li>

                <li>
                    <label for="address">Address:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="user_address" id="address" size="50" />
                </li>

                <li>
                    <label for="city">City:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="city" id="city" size="30" />
                </li>

                <li>
                    <label for="state">State:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="state" id="state" size="30" />
                </li>

                <li>
                    <label for="zip">Zip code:</label>
                    <input type="number" name="zip" id="zip" size="7" />
                </li>

                <li>
                    <label for="phone">Phone Number:</label>
                    <input type="number" name="phone" id="phone" size="15" />
                </li>

                <li>
                    <label for="email">Email Address:</label>
                    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" size="25" placeholder="youremail@gmail.com" />
                </li>

                <li>
                    <label for="birthday">Your Birthday</label>
                    <input type="date" name="birthday" id="birthday" size="20" />
                </li>

                <li>
                    <label for="favoritecolor">Choose your favorite Color:</label>
                    <input type="color" name="color" id="favoritecolor" size="10" />
                </li>

                <li>
                    <label for="country">Country:</label>
                    <select name="country">
                        <option selected="" value="Default">(Please choose a country)</option>
                        <option value="JA">Japan</option>
                        <option value="AU">Australia</option>
                        <option value="US">United States</option>
                        <option value="GM">Germany</option>
                        <option value="AF">Africa</option>
                        <option value="RU">Russia</option>
                        <option value="IT">Italy</option>
                    </select>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <label for="rumNum">Number of Rummage Sales Attended</label>
                    <input type="number" name="rumsale" id="rumNum" size="7" />

                </li>
            </ul>

            <div class="Ebay">
                <h6> Do you use Ebay to sell your items?</h6>
                <label for="yes">Yes</label>
                <input type="radio" name="radio-1" id="yes">
                <label for="no">No</label>
                <input type="radio" name="radio-1" id="no">
            </div>

            <div class="payment">
                <h6>Select a Form of Payment:</h6>
                <label for="paypal">Paypal</label>
                <input type="radio" name="radio-3" id="paypal">
                <label for="CC">Credit Card</label>
                <input type="radio" name="radio-3" id="CC">
                <label for="Check">Check</label>
                <input type="radio" name="radio-3" id="Check">
                <label for="Cash">Cash</label>
                <input type="radio" name="radio-3" id="Cash">
            </div>

            <div>
               <div class="favRum">
                <h6>Favorite Rummage Items:</h6>
                <input type="checkbox" name="Fish" value="Fish">Fish Tanks
                <input type="checkbox" name="Dresser" value="Dresser">Dressers
                <input type="checkbox" name="Lamp" value="Lamp">Lamps
                <input type="checkbox" name="Boots" value="Boots">Boots
            </div><br />

            <input type="hidden" id="mySecret" value="Classified" />
            <button id="output" type="button">Submit Form</button>
            <input id="btnReset" type="reset" value="Clear form" /><br /><br />
      </div>
      </div>
    </form>
    <div id="results"></div>
      <hr>
</main>

<!-- Footer Information -->
<footer class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <p>&copy; Copyright data</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <p>Contact info</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <p>About Us</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>

<div id="result"></div>



<script>
function registrationform() {
var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
var city = document.getElementById("city").value;
var zip = document.getElementById("zip").value;
var state = document.getElementById("state").value;
var country = document.getElementById("country").value;
var phone = document.getElementById("phone").value;
var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
var pass = document.getElementById("pass").value;
var favoritecolor = document.getElementById("favoritecolor").value;
var birthday = document.getElementById("birthday").value;
var rumSale = document.getElementById("rumSale").value;
var mySecret = document.getElementById("mySecret").value;
var ebay = "";
var Yes = document.getElementById("Yes").checked;
var No = document.getElementById("No").checked;
if (Yes) {
    ebay
        = document.getElementById("Yes").value;
}
    if (No) {
        Ebay = document.getElementById("No").value;
}
var payment = "";
var Paypal = document.getElementById("paypal").checked;
var Credit = document.getElementById("CC").checked;
var Cash = document.getElementById("Cash").checked;
var Check = document.getElementById("Check").checked;
if (Paypal) {
payment = document.getElementById("paypal").value;
}
else if (Credit) {
payment = document.getElementById("CC").value;
}
else if (Cash) {
payment = document.getElementById("cash").value;
}
else if (Check) {
payment = document.getElementById("check").value;
}
var fish = document.getElementById("fish").checked;
var dresser = document.getElementById("dresser").checked;
var boots = document.getElementById("boots").checked;
var lamp = document.getElementById("lamp").checked

var favRum = "";
if (fish) {
    favRum += document.getElementById("fish").value + " ";
    }
     if (dresser) {
        favRum += document.getElementById("dresser").value + " ";
     }
         if (boots) {
             favRum += document.getElementById("boots").value;
         }
            if (lamp) {
                 favRum += document.getElementById("lamp").value;
            }
}
    //Output
var welcome = 'Welcome: ' + name + "<br />"
              'Address: ' + address + ", " + city + state + ", " + country + " " + zip + "<br />"
              'Phone Number: ' + phone + "<br />" 
              'Email Address: ' + email + "<br />" 
              'Password: ' + pass + "<br />" + "<h3>Preferences</h3>" 
              'Favorite Color: ' + favoritecolor + "<br />" 
              'Date of Birth: ' + birthday + "<br />" 
              'Number of Rummage Sales attended: ' + rumSale + "<br />" 
              'My secret code word is: ' + mySecret + "<br />" 
              'Do you sell on Ebay? ' + ebay + "<br />" 
              'Preferred Payment method: ' + payment + "<br />" 
              'Favorite Rummage: ' + favRum;


    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = welcome

    document.getElementById('output').addEventListener('click', registrationform);
</script>
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.  I am new to coding of all kinds.  Thank you.

Comment: Can you add the html? Also why is there a <div> in your script?

Comment: FYI `Ebay` !== `ebay`, case matters.  Ans strings do not have styles so `text.style = "background-color:" + Favoritecolor;` is not going to do anything. Finally `text` is never declared so the `text += ....` line will throw an error. You really need to look t your error console when you code!

Comment: We are missing one part of the code. How is registrationform called?

Comment: Thank you epascarello.  I made some changes, let me know if this is what you mean.

Comment: @steven can you add you result and output id html in the code .

Comment: When I click submit, it goes to the top of the page.

Comment: Here is the entire code with HTML and javascript.

Answer (score 0):

There are many typo's in your html. Several elements does not have `id` (`name` is not enough to use `document.getElementById` method), eg: "country", "rumSale", "fish", "dresser", "lamp", "boots", The "results" is typed wrongly as "result"...

Also note that the `id` is case sensitive and "Yes" is different than 'yes'.

The `welcome` var statement at end of your code needs to be defined before closing function brace `}` and the `+` sign is need at end of each line of it. The `document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = welcome;` line must also be moved to inside the function. (It seems that you have defined results two times, i remove the last one in footer)

Here is you corrected code:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-
 JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" 
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/homework.css" type="text/css" media="screen">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark fixed-top bg-dark">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">CS240</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarsExampleDefault" aria-controls="navbarsExampleDefault" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item active">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="dropdown01" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Products</a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown01">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Rummage Items</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Unique Items</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Love that Ink Pen Company</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="dropdown02" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Who we are</a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown02">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">About Us</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Our Vision</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Contact Us</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" id="dropdown03" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Links</a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown03">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="../pages/home.html">Home</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="../pages/week1-1.html">Week 1-1</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="../pages/week1-2.html">Week 1-2</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="../pages/week2-1.html">Week 2-1</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="../pages/week2-2.html">Week 2-2</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="../pages/week3-1.html">Week 3-1</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="../pages/week3-2.html">Week 3-2</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="../pages/week4-1.html">Week 4-1</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="../pages/week4-2.html">Week 4-2</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="../pages/week5-1.html">Week 5-1</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="../pages/week5-2.html">Week 5-2</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="../pages/week6-1.html">Week 6-1</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="../pages/week6-2.html">Week 6-2</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="../pages/week7-1.html">Week 7-1</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="../pages/week7-2.html">Week 7-2</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="../pages/week8-1.html">Week 8-1</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="../pages/week8-2.html">Week 8-2</a>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit"></button>
        </form>
    </div>
</nav>

<main role="main">

    <!--Main jumbotron-->
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <h1 class="display-3">Registration</h1>
            <p>Please fill out the information</p>
            <blockquote class="blockquote text-center">
                <p class="mb-0">"Rummage through it all!"</p>
                <footer class="blockquote-footer">Someone Awesome <cite title="Source Title"></cite></footer>
            </blockquote>
        </div>
        <!--Card to display a logo-->
        <div class="card" style="width: 18rem; color:black">
            <img class="card-img-top" src="../images/registration.jpg" alt="Card image cap">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title"></h5>
                <p class="card-text">Register Today!</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <form style="background:url(../images/Backgroundcontainer.png)">
        <div class="container-fluid">

            <h1>Registration Form</h1>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <label for="pass">Password:</label>
                    <input type="password" name="pass" id="pass" size="30" placeholder="Minimum 10 characters long" />
                </li>

                <li>
                    <label for="name">Name:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="user_name" id="name" size="50" placeholder="Firstname, LastName Mi" />
                </li>

                <li>
                    <label for="address">Address:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="user_address" id="address" size="50" />
                </li>

                <li>
                    <label for="city">City:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="city" id="city" size="30" />
                </li>

                <li>
                    <label for="state">State:</label>
                    <input type="text" name="state" id="state" size="30" />
                </li>

                <li>
                    <label for="zip">Zip code:</label>
                    <input type="number" name="zip" id="zip" size="7" />
                </li>

                <li>
                    <label for="phone">Phone Number:</label>
                    <input type="number" name="phone" id="phone" size="15" />
                </li>

                <li>
                    <label for="email">Email Address:</label>
                    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" size="25" placeholder="youremail@gmail.com" />
                </li>

                <li>
                    <label for="birthday">Your Birthday</label>
                    <input type="date" name="birthday" id="birthday" size="20" />
                </li>

                <li>
                    <label for="favoritecolor">Choose your favorite Color:</label>
                    <input type="color" name="color" id="favoritecolor" size="10" />
                </li>

                <li>
                    <label for="country">Country:</label>
                    <select id="country" name="country">
                        <option selected="" value="Default">(Please choose a country)</option>
                        <option value="JA">Japan</option>
                        <option value="AU">Australia</option>
                        <option value="US">United States</option>
                        <option value="GM">Germany</option>
                        <option value="AF">Africa</option>
                        <option value="RU">Russia</option>
                        <option value="IT">Italy</option>
                    </select>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <label for="rumSale">Number of Rummage Sales Attended</label>
                    <input type="number" name="rumSale" id="rumSale" size="7" />

                </li>
            </ul>

            <div class="Ebay">
                <h6> Do you use Ebay to sell your items?</h6>
                <label for="yes">Yes</label>
                <input type="radio" name="radio-1" id="yes">
                <label for="no">No</label>
                <input type="radio" name="radio-1" id="no">
            </div>

            <div class="payment">
                <h6>Select a Form of Payment:</h6>
                <label for="paypal">Paypal</label>
                <input type="radio" name="radio-3" id="Paypal">
                <label for="CC">Credit Card</label>
                <input type="radio" name="radio-3" id="CC">
                <label for="Check">Check</label>
                <input type="radio" name="radio-3" id="Check">
                <label for="Cash">Cash</label>
                <input type="radio" name="radio-3" id="Cash">
            </div>

            <div>
                <div class="favRum">
                    <h6>Favorite Rummage Items:</h6>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="Fish" id="fish" value="Fish">Fish Tanks
                    <input type="checkbox" name="Dresser" id="dresser" value="Dresser">Dressers
                    <input type="checkbox" name="Lamp" id="lamp" value="Lamp">Lamps
                    <input type="checkbox" name="Boots" id="boots" value="Boots">Boots
                </div><br />

                <input type="hidden" id="mySecret" value="Classified" />
                <button id="output" type="button">Submit Form</button>
                <input id="btnReset" type="reset" value="Clear form" /><br /><br />
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <div id="results" style="border:2px solid red;">***results</div>
    <hr>
</main>

<!-- Footer Information -->
<footer class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <p>&copy; Copyright data</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <p>Contact info</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <p>About Us</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>

<div id="result"></div>



<script type="text/javascript">
    function registrationform() {
        var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
        var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
        var city = document.getElementById("city").value;
        var zip = document.getElementById("zip").value;
        var state = document.getElementById("state").value;
        var country = document.getElementById("country").value;
        var phone = document.getElementById("phone").value;
        var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
        var pass = document.getElementById("pass").value;
        var favoritecolor = document.getElementById("favoritecolor").value;
        var birthday = document.getElementById("birthday").value;
        var rumSale = document.getElementById("rumSale").value;
        var mySecret = document.getElementById("mySecret").value;
        var ebay = "";
        var Yes = document.getElementById("yes").checked;
        var No = document.getElementById("no").checked;
        if (Yes) {
            ebay = "Yes";
        }
        if (No) {
            ebay = "No";
        }
        var payment = "";
        var Paypal = document.getElementById("Paypal").checked;
        var Credit = document.getElementById("CC").checked;
        var Cash = document.getElementById("Cash").checked;
        var Check = document.getElementById("Check").checked;
        
  payment = (Paypal ? "Paypal" : Credit ? "CC" : Cash ? "Cash" : Check ? "Check" : "");
        /*if (Paypal) {
            payment = "Paypal";
        }
        else if (Credit) {
            payment = "CC";
        }
        else if (Cash) {
            payment = "Cash";
        }
        else if (Check) {
            payment = "Check";
        }*/
        
        var fish = document.getElementById("fish").checked;
        var dresser = document.getElementById("dresser").checked;
        var boots = document.getElementById("boots").checked;
        var lamp = document.getElementById("lamp").checked

        var favRum = "";
        if (fish) {
            favRum += document.getElementById("fish").value + " ";
        }

        if (dresser) {
            favRum += document.getElementById("dresser").value + " ";
        }
        if (boots) {
            favRum += document.getElementById("boots").value;
        }
        if (lamp) {
            favRum += document.getElementById("lamp").value;
        }

        //Output
        var welcome = 'Welcome: ' + name + "<br />" +
            'Address: ' + address + ", " + city + state + ", " + country + " " + zip + "<br />" +
            'Phone Number: ' + phone + "<br />" +
            'Email Address: ' + email + "<br />" +
            'Password: ' + pass + "<br />" + "<h3>Preferences</h3>" +
            'Favorite Color: ' + favoritecolor + "<br />" +
            'Date of Birth: ' + birthday + "<br />" +
            'Number of Rummage Sales attended: ' + rumSale + "<br />" +
            'My secret code word is: ' + mySecret + "<br />" +
            'Do you sell on Ebay? ' + ebay + "<br />" +
            'Preferred Payment method: ' + payment + "<br />" +
            'Favorite Rummage: ' + favRum;


        document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = welcome;


    } //end of function

    document.getElementById('output').addEventListener('click', registrationform);

</script>
```

Another note: instead of `document.getElementById`, you can use jquery `$('#id')` or define a simple function to access those several elements more easily.

```
//instead of these:
//var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
//var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
//var city = document.getElementById("city").value;
//...

//you can use jquery `$('#id')` or define a simple function eg:
function getId(id) { return document.getElementById(id); }

var name = getId("name").value; //or: $("#name").val();
var address = getId("address").value;
var city = getId("city").value;
...
```

Comment: Awesome thank you.  Quick secondary question, when I click the submit form button and I look at the ebay and preferred payment method.  Is there something that should be changed to alter what the output is.  I keep getting the word "on". When I hit submit.

Comment: @steven Yes, the code is updated. you need to write something like `if (Paypal) { payment = "Paypal"; } else if (Credit) { payment = "CC"; } ...` as `payment` should be the output meaningful string and it doesn't need `checked` status of inputs. you can combine those `if's`with conditional `?:` operator as shown in updated code.

Comment: @steven please take a look and if this post is useful, up-vote and accept it as answer ;D